# Cannot compile PHP statically when adding `--with-readline`

Tags: php, static-libraries, readline, ncurses

I compiled php 8.1.7 statically in Alpine Linux latest version, and I made it with following command.

```bash
./configure LDFLAGS=-static --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-mbstring --enable-static=yes
sed -ie 's/-export-dynamic//g' "Makefile" && \
    sed -ie 's/-o $(SAPI_CLI_PATH)/-all-static -o $(SAPI_CLI_PATH)/g' "Makefile"
make LDFLAGS="-ldl" -j12
make install
```

Then add readline.

```bash
apk add readline readline-dev readline-static ncurses-static ncurses-dev
./configure LDFLAGS=-static --disable-all --enable-cli --enable-mbstring --enable-static=yes --with-readline
```

Error messages here.

```
checking for libedit readline replacement... no
checking for readline support... yes
checking for tgetent in -lncurses... no
checking for tgetent in -ltermcap... no
checking for readline in -lreadline... no
configure: error: readline library not found
```

And `config.log` part is

```
configure:84994: checking for tgetent in -lncurses
configure:85017: cc -o conftest -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -static conftest.c -lncurses  -lrt -lm  >&5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -lncurses
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:85027: result: no
configure:85059: checking for tgetent in -ltermcap
configure:85082: cc -o conftest -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -static conftest.c -ltermcap  -lrt -lm  >&5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: cannot find -ltermcap
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:85092: result: no
configure:85235: checking for readline in -lreadline
configure:85258: cc -o conftest -g -O2 -fvisibility=hidden  -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -static conftest.c -lreadline  -lrt -lm  >&5
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.a(display.o): in function `_rl_move_cursor_r
elative':
/root/static-php-cli/docker/source/readline-8.1/display.c:2805: undefined reference to `tputs'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.a(display.o): in function `_rl_move_vert':
/root/static-php-cli/docker/source/readline-8.1/display.c:2857: undefined reference to `tputs'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/10.3.1/../../../../x86_64-alpine-linux-musl/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libreadline.a(terminal.o):/root/static-php-cli/docker/source/readline-8
.1/terminal.c:764: more undefined references to `tputs' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
configure:85268: result: no
configure:85381: error: readline library not found
```

Comment: maybe missing libreadline-dev? `apk add --upgrade readline-dev`

Comment: I added it, but it has no effect.

Comment: oh yes you listed it on your add line and I didn't notice... anyway looking on the web I found some hints but are just hints.. like find out if the compiler isn't using the corrector dir (I don't know how to find out.. maybe checking some log file highlighting the compile failure in detail?).Trying also to disable readline with --without-readline (I don't know how the result is affected). I was not helpful with straight hints but maybe(!) you can find further suggestion in a page I found here: https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=00750-78904b31-818f-4fca-8a63-4a905e390673 Good luck.

Comment: I have edited the question and attached the part of `config.log`, maybe caused by ncurses?

Answer (score 0):

I made it. And the solution is very simple.

Just move `/usr/lib/libreadline.so*`, `/usr/lib/libncurses*.so*` to another directory. After compilation move them back to `/usr/lib/`.